# iterating over a group-by result of pandas dataframe and operate on each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data-frame 2*N

```
eventcode filename
ET0001    A.csv
ET0001    B.csv
ET0002    C.csv
ET0002    D.csv
ET0002    E.csv
ET0003    F.csv
ET0003    G.csv
```

i need to iterate and for each event-code group i want to read each .csv file in the group and append them to a final data-frame.

In this case, I need something like

```
ET0001 df_AB.csv    ###(name is like this but actually they formed after appending A.csv and B.csv)
ET0002 df_CDE.csv
ET0003 df_FG.csv
```

what I have tried doing is

A function to merge

```
 def finalmerge(d):
     dff = pd.read_csv(str(d))
     v = dff.append(dff,ignore_index=True)
     return v
```

then doing a grouby and iteration

```
g = df.groupby('EVENT_CODE')
for name, group in g:
    f = group['filename'].apply(finalmerge)
```

But not getting the expected.

May be it can be done without using a groupby, but sorry, I am not getting it, so tried using a groupby.

please suggest a code example. Using groupby or without a group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applied 2 nested for loops and solved

```
for x in df['EVENT_CODE'].unique():
       df1 = df[df['EVENT_CODE'] == x]
       c = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns)
       for file in df1['filename']:
           d = pd.read_csv(str(file))
           c = c.append(d,ignore_index=True)
```

if c is filterout from second for loop.I got the appended file.

Answer (score 3):

You can start off with a function that `concat`s the `DataFrame`s of each group:

```
def generate_dataframes_of_group(g):
    return pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in g.filename.values])
```

Then just `groupby` and `apply`:

```
df.groupby(df.eventcode).apply(generate_dataframes_of_groups)
```